# Prevent emacs from calling melpa/updating on startup

Tags: package-repositories, start-up

This is already the 2nd time I can't start emacs as one single package on a server can't be found.
My current configuration works fine and I'd rather have a reliable system than one that is always up to date. Last time I had to write the package-maintainer to put his website up again.

Or are there other solutions?

[image]

Comment: Emacs *doesn't* talk to melpa or update anything on startup.  Or not unless *you've* told it to do that, at any rate.  So review your config and stop telling it to do this.

Comment: It also looks like you need to add the `compat` package to your config.

Comment: @phils - added it. No difference. Also on startup I always get `Contacting host: elpa.gnu.org:443`

Comment: Well, it's your config so you'll need to debug it -- you're the only one who knows what's in it.  Start by using `--debug-init` as instructed; that should point you to what it is which is triggering that error.  A good method of debugging is the "recursive bisection" method, which can quickly narrow down the source of issues when you don't know where to look.  Some searching should explain how that works if it's new to you.  That's about all I can offer.

Comment: @phils - I haven't done any changes for about 3 months to my config.

Comment: Well apparently your config checks for updates when you start Emacs, so maybe you also had it auto-updating packages, in which case you've potentially had *many* updates in the last 3 months.

Comment: FWIW I'm dubious that you've succeeded in installing `compat`, so I think you should update your question with the details of *exactly* what you did when you were attempting that, and how you tested afterwards.  And if it's still not working, then you also need to add the backtrace from `--debug-init` to your question.

Comment: Solved by updating the list of packages by pressing U